# butler doesn't show jenkins data

Tags: package

I'm working with GNU Emacs 26.1
I have troubles with setting up [butler](https://github.com/AshtonKem/Butler/).

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/deferred-20170901.1330/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/butler-20150812.8/")
(require 'butler)
(add-to-list 'butler-server-list
             '(jenkins "SERVER-NAME"
                       (server-address . "https://<server>:443")
                       (server-user . "<username>")
                       (server-password . "<password>")))
```

When i try to run `butler-status`i see this in *Messages* buffer:

```
Contacting host: <server>:443
deferred error : (error "Bad bounding indices: -6, nil")
```

I haven't found a way do debug this issue.
As the traffic flows through https, i can't see actual request and response.
Also I'm bad at lisp so looking at butler's *.el files doesn't help :)

Comment: i would be grateful for any info on how can i debug this :)

Comment: i have also commented in github issue similar to one i have:
https://github.com/AshtonKem/Butler/issues/18